# override core rules in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I wanted  to override core rule for number  in yii2 to convert persian numbers to english numbers, and then validate them?
these code uses for converting persian numbers to english numbers in php

```
function convert($string) {
    $persian = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
    $num = range(0, 9);
    return str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
}
```

How can I apply these codes for doing convert before validation?I don't want to use beforeValidate in my model
I wrote a componet but I don't know what function and where should be change?

Answer (score 1):

Add `filter` rule in the model.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['pers_number', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
            return str_replace(
                ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'], 
                range(0, 9),
                $value
            );
        }],
    ];
}
```